# Spinner adapter badly rendered

Tags: android

I have an autocomplete spinner with an adapter that usually looks like this:

[image]

Thing is, sometime it is rendered like this:

[image]

I found that a way to reproduce it is to click again in the Spinner while the dropdown is open, which causes it to be rendered again.

This is the xml for the adapter item (vertical padding is 8 dp):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:src="@drawable/artboard"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_padding"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        tools:text="Competition name"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with

```
android:paddingTop="x"
android:paddingBottom="x"
```

It will add a margin at the top and the bottom of the components.